# Deactivating a contact for a certain timeframe

Tags: contacts

I have following issue. We got an email from an business partner. She will not be working for the next 1.5 years. After that time she will be back. She asked us to use during this time a different (general address) email address. This address is already connected to the company.  Now I am wondering if it is possible to deactivate this contact for that specific time in terms of not losing a contact. Of course it should be reactivated automatically because I do not know if I will be responsible for our contacts at this time in the future.

This would be the best way to keep her contact in the database and nobody has to remember reactivating the contact.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to add an Activity on her record with a Scheduled Date for 18 months time, and assign it to a contact that has an email address that will still be read in 18 months. that way you could change her email address to the one she wants using, or set her Comms Prefs to 'do not email', and then in 18 months they should receive a reminder to undo things so she gets the emails again.